# Are help() and license() functions but copyright and credits not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Python prompt gives option to do the following.

Check help, copyright, credits, and license.

It is must to use () with help and license but not with copyright and credits. Just wondering why?

I have tried running all these by with and without (). help and license specifically ask to type ().

Comment: You can answer that with a simple `type(name)` for any defined name.

Comment: @KlausD.: If you try that you'll see it's not that simple.  Some of these 4 have the same type but behave differently.

Comment: Thanks Klaus. I tried type(name) on all needed names, help shows as a _Helper function and remaining all _Printer, i hope remaining are only meant for printing. This still leaves the doubt why it is must to use () with help and license.

Comment: Apologies, I am new to Python. _Helper and _Printer classes under _sitebuiltins modules.

Answer (score 0):

The `copyright` and `credits` builtin print out like simple strings. That works for them because they're each relatively short (just a few lines each). They're actually instances of a class (so you *can* call them), but you don't need to.

For `license` and `help`, there's far too much information for a single string to contain in a user-friendly manner. When you run `license()`, it shows you one page of the license at a time, with a prompt to press return to see more. The `help` builtin is even more fancy, as it gives you an interactive prompt to get help on a variety of different topics (including giving separate help texts for every module you have installed). You can also call `help` on an object (such as a function or module) to get more narrowly directed help without going through the interactive system.

Comment: Thanks @Blcknght. Your answer sounds logical to me. I am still trying to figure our technical implementation of these.

Comment: A nice thing about Python is that it's open source, so you can go read the implementation pretty easily. You can find the definition of the two classes that implement `copyright`, `credits`, `license` and `help` in [the `_sitebuiltins` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/45a14942c969ed508b35abd5e116cb18f84ce5b4/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py), and then see where instances of them are created by [the `site` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/45a14942c969ed508b35abd5e116cb18f84ce5b4/Lib/site.py).

Comment: Definitely, will be doing that. Today is my first day of starting with Python. I hope to reach there in some time.

Comment: Found copyright is defined in Python/getcopyright.c as a static char array. In sys modules, it is defined as a string rather than a function. This is my assumption that when we type copyright on python interpreter prompt, it doesn't pick it from sys. It rather takes it from builtins where it is defined as callable so it can printed as a string or called as a function but still does the same job. I would really appreciate, if you guys could correct me here.

Comment: Yes, the `site` module I linked earlier constructs instances of `_sitebuiltins._Printer` for `copyright`, `credits` and `license`, and injects them into the `builtins` module. Their text is either from a string (a literal in the `site.py` source for `credits` and `sys.copyright` for `copyright`), or read from a text file (in the case of `license`).